# how to add different flavours of same application(want to clone the application) with differnt google-services.json file in android project?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, gradle, google-play-services

I want to clone my android app and launch it with a different name and a fresh new database in a different region, I don't want to write the code all over again or make a duplicate copy of the project. i used productFlavour{} in my build.gradle file in project, but i couldnt get it right.

```
        flavour1 {
            dimension 'default'
            applicationId "com.example.flavour1"
        }

        flavour2 {
            dimension 'default'
            applicationId "com.example.flavour2"
        }
```

I am getting this error that says

```
No signature of method: build_7epdrck7cjxe08sh65acsfob0.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_7epdrck7cjxe08sh65acsfob0$_run_closure1) values: [build_7epdrck7cjxe08sh65acsfob0$_run_closure1@29754fbc]
```

I also created two folders under my project src/ root folder with the same names of flavour1 and flavour2 and added their respective google-service.json file. but it's not working.
am I doing anything wrong?

this is my whole gradle file code except dependencies

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.scs"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            renderscriptDebuggable false
            pseudoLocalesEnabled false
            zipAlignEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
                    'proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavours{
         flavour1 {
            dimension 'default'
            applicationId "com.example.flavour1"
        }

        flavour2 {
            dimension 'default'
            applicationId "com.example.flavour2"
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = true
    }
}
```

any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Comment: You are missing `flavorDimensions "default"` before `productFlavors` declaration

Comment: hi @MatPag, thanks for the quick reply.  I tried your comment, but that didn't fix my issue.

Comment: You probably have a syntax error somewhere, try commenting some part of your gradle until it build fine

Comment: @MatPag, thanks for the suggestion, i got it fixed. there was a type in productFlavor,  i worte it as productFlavours where as it should be productFlavors.